# iOS App crash just before termination?

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, crash, ios5

There are some times when my app would presumably crash when I hit the "Stop" button on xcode when debugging.

I assume it's crashing because I get a bunch of stuff in the Xcode debug navigator under several threads but the debug session terminates soon after and there isn't enough time to look over what's going on. It's stops in a line within the "main" method of main.m for a very, very brief moment.

The debug console dosen't give me a stack trace.

How can I debug this? I'm using the new Xcode 4.2.

Comment: From what I know of XCode, to terminate your app, it sends a SIGKILL signal. This alone 'crashes' your app. As to the information in your debugger window, I'm not sure why you're getting that. Is it the same kind of info when you unplug the device during a build?

Comment: What makes you think it crashed?  Is there a crash message in the console log?  If so please post it.

Comment: I'm using the simulator, haven't tested it enough on an actual device and it's pretty inconsistent so I can't really be sure.

Comment: What is the console log from the simulator?

Comment: CocoaFu// Usually when I hit "Stop" on Xcode, the app closes immediately. But when it "crashes", xcode sends me to main.m and stops for a split second then terminates. The debug navigator (on the left pannel) also shows me a list of threads for a brief moment then disappears. Very strange.

Comment: Also, like I said, the consol log gives me nothing which makes it more puzzling.

Comment: I think I had an error like that one time that was repeatable. The cause if I remember correctly was an overreleased object. It was probably supposed to have a retain count of 2, but it had a count of 1, and as the app was shutting down it got 2 release messages causing a release to a dealloc'ed object. But yeah sometimes I get it just intermittently when I've been using the debugger. I would like to know the answer too.

Comment: I would suspect the same thing as @morningstar: an over-released object that crashes your app. Try to turn on the debug/zombie mode for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is nothing in the console log the app didn't crash.

Comment: For now at least, this seems to be the most plausible answer.

Comment: When you stop in Xcode exactly that happens, it stops wherever it is.  To get `applicationWillTerminate` and etc. called click the home button on the simulator or the device.

Answer (score 2):

When your App "crashes" OS writes it to a crashreport. Look at ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/ folder and Look for most recent crash report of your app there. If that doesn't help you place a breakpoint in your appWillTerminate and then in your debug console look at stack trace what gets called. You said you get bunch of stuff in XCode debug navigator under several threads ? Can you paste that messages from debug console here.

Comment: I did not find anything in the DiagnosticReports directory, does this mean that the app in fact didn't crash? In any case, I wasn't able to get to the bottom of this problem. I forgot about it and moved a lot code around and it seems to have went away, just not sure what it was I did. Putting breakpoints in appWillTerminate was a great tip though.

Comment: Update- applicationWillTerminate, applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillResignActive does NOT get called when you hit "stop" from Xcode